# Show all taxonomy's terms' posts having another taxonomy's term in common

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I am building a website which displays web radio stations. I have created a custom post type called "stations" and 2 taxonomies called "genres" and "locations". In my page I display all genres grouped by genre no matter what the location is.
The code:

```
<?php function get_stations_query($current_genre) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type'      => 'stations',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby'        => 'title',
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $current_genre
                                    )
                                )
                        ) );
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop-stations');
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); else : ?>
        <p>Sorry, no radio stations found.</p>
    <?php endif; } ?>
<?php function generate_genres() {
    $genresrays = array (
        'pop_genre'       => 'Pop',
        'rock_genre'      => 'Rock',
        'jazz_genre'      => 'Jazz',
        'soul_genre'      => 'Soul',
        'ethnic_genre'    => 'Ethnic',
        'trance_genre'    => 'Trance',
        'country_genre'   => 'Country',
        'chill_out_genre' => 'Chill Out',
    );
    foreach ($genresrays as $genresray=>$genre_value) {
        $ex_term = term_exists($genre_value, 'genres');
        if ($ex_term !== 0 && $ex_term !== null) { ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr style="margin: 30px 0;">
            <div id="<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$genre_value)); ?>" class="clearfix">
                <h3 style="margin-top: 20px !important;"><?php echo $genre_value; ?></h3><br>
                <?php get_stations_query(strtolower($genre_value)); ?>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
} ?>
```

I use `<?php generate_genres(); ?>` to display the output. What I am struggling to do with no success is displaying the exact same output by simultaneously query-ing those posts by "location" taxonomy too (in my `taxonomy-locations.php`), so for example posts will be displayed like this:

```
-- POP --------------------
    Station X (USA)
    Station Y (USA)

-- ROCK -------------------
    Station C (USA)
    Station F (USA)

-- JAZZ -------------------
    Station L (USA)
    Station K (USA)

-- SOUL -------------------
    Station Z (USA)
    Station R (USA)
```

In my custom taxonomy template I display the current taxonomy name as a heading by using this:

```
<?php $loc_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); echo $loc_term->name; ?>
```

I am trying to achieve the desired result by querying the posts by 2 taxonomies simultaneously with `'relation' => 'AND'` but it doesn't work. I tried lots of variations but in the best case scenario I got all the stations being displayed but taxonomy "locations" was completely ignored. How should I do it?

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    $loc_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type'      => 'stations',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby'        => 'title',
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $current_genre,
                                        'operator' => 'AND'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $loc_term
                                    )
                                )
                        ) );
?>
```

After changing the posts query (the code above) I managed to have only proper posts displayed however `genres` (custom taxonomy) with no posts attached are still being displayed. Anyone know why/how to fix this?

Here is an example of what I get

```
-- POP --------------------
        Station X (USA)
        Station Y (USA)

-- ROCK -------------------  <- BLANK (shouldn't be displayed)
-- JAZZ -------------------  <- BLANK (shouldn't be displayed)

-- SOUL -------------------
    Station Z (USA)
    Station R (USA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work properly. I am posting the solution so maybe other people need something similar can use it.
It seems what I needed to do is use `get_posts` with the same arguments as `WP_Query` and check if there are posts by modifying the "if" statement already existed inside "foreach".

**All code**

```
<?php function get_stations_query($current_genre) {
    $loc_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type'      => 'stations',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby'        => 'title',
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $current_genre,
                                        'operator' => 'AND'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $loc_term->name
                                    )
                                )
                        ) );
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop-stations');
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); else : ?>
        <p>Sorry, no radio stations found.</p>
    <?php endif;
} ?>

<?php function generate_genres() {
    $genresrays = array (
        'pop_genre'       => 'Pop',
        'rock_genre'      => 'Rock',
        'jazz_genre'      => 'Jazz',
        'soul_genre'      => 'Soul',
        'ethnic_genre'    => 'Ethnic',
        'trance_genre'    => 'Trance',
        'country_genre'   => 'Country',
        'chill_out_genre' => 'Chill Out',
    );

    foreach ($genresrays as $genresray=>$genre_value) {
        $ex_term = term_exists($genre_value, 'genres');
        $loc_term_s = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

        $grab = get_posts(array(
                            'post_type'      => 'stations',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $genre_value,
                                        'operator' => 'AND'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                                        'field'    => 'name',
                                        'terms'    => $loc_term_s->name
                                    )
                            ))
                );

        if (!empty($grab) && $ex_term !== 0 && $ex_term !== null) { ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr style="margin: 30px 0;">
            <div id="<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$genre_value)); ?>" class="clearfix">
                <h3 style="margin-top: 20px !important;"><?php echo $genre_value; ?></h3><br>
                <?php get_stations_query(strtolower($genre_value)); ?>
            </div>
        <?php }

    }
} ?>
```